# How to add rows dynamically to datatable using jquery ajax call

Tags: html, jquery, datatables

I want to add rows dynamically to datatable using jquery ajax call and while adding rows dynamically I'm getting error

> caught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'style')

I didn't understand this and I unable to resolve this error.

This is what I have tried so far

Using CDN links are:

```
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.13.1/css/jquery.dataTables.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<!-- data table -->
    <link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.13.1/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.4.0/css/responsive.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

    <link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/2.3.6/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/2.3.6/js/buttons.html5.min.js" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/2.3.6/js/buttons.print.min.js" rel="stylesheet" />

 <!-- Data Table -->

    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.13.1/js/jquery.dataTables.js" type="text/javascript"
        charset="utf8"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.4.0/js/dataTables.responsive.min.js"></script>
```

HTML:

```
<table class="viewportcmntbl table responsive tdmaintbl dtr-inline dataTable" id="DataTables_Table_0">
    <thead>
        <tr class="rectblnobreakhead" role="row">
            <th>Scrip Name</th>
            <th>B/S</th>
            <th>Qty</th>
            <th>Entry Price (<i class="fa fa-inr"></i>)</th>
            <th>Tgt</th>
            <th>SL</th>
            <th>LTP</th>
            <th>TPL</th>
            <th>Inv.</th>
            <th>Period</th>
            <th>Entry Time</th>
            <th>Max PL</th>
            <th>Max&nbsp;PL&nbsp;%</th>
            <th>Status</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

JQuery:

```
$('#DataTables_Table_0').DataTable({
        dom: 'Bfrtip',
        data: intsignl,
        columns: [
            {
                render: function (data, type, row, meta) {
                    return meta.row + meta.settings._iDisplayStart + 1;
                }
            },

            { data: 'ScripName' },
            { data: 'BuySell' },
            { data: 'Qty' },
            { data: 'EntryPrice' },
            { data: 'Tgt' },
            { data: 'SL' },
            { data: 'LTP' },
            { data: 'TotPL' },
            { data: 'Investment' },
            { data: 'Period' },
            { data: 'EntryTime' },
            { data: 'MaxPL' },
            { data: 'aStatus' },
            { data: 'MaxPLPerReached' }
        ],

        "paging": true,
        "info": true,
        "language": {
            "emptyTable": "No data available"
        },
        "fnRowCallback": function (nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex) {
            $("td:first", nRow).html(iDisplayIndex + 1);
            return nRow;
        },
    });
```

`data: intsignl` in this intsignl I'm getting the Json data and returning  that data as `return JSON.parse(sus);` so as per this image I'm getting the data

[image: Output image]

Getting this error:

[image: Error message image]

JSon output format is:

```
[
   {
      "ScripName":"BANKNIFTY23APRFUT",
      "BuySell":"BUY",
      "Qty":25,
      "EntryPrice":41872.75,
      "Tgt":42105.15,
      "SL":42027.7,
      "LTP":42105.15,
      "TotPL":5810.0,
      "Investment":154301.0,
      "Period":"Intraday",
      "EntryTime":"2023-04-13 13:40:57",
      "MaxPL":5810.0,
      "aStatus":"TGT Reached",
      "MaxPLPerReached":100.0
   },
   {
      "ScripName":"NIFTY23APRFUT",
      "BuySell":"SELL",
      "Qty":50,
      "EntryPrice":17798.15,
      "Tgt":17749.15,
      "SL":17847.15,
      "LTP":17847.15,
      "TotPL":-2450.0,
      "Investment":105632.0,
      "Period":"Intraday",
      "EntryTime":"2023-04-13 11:03:14",
      "MaxPL":1157.5,
      "aStatus":"SL Reached",
      "MaxPLPerReached":47.24
   },
   {
      "ScripName":"BANKNIFTY23APRFUT",
      "BuySell":"SELL",
      "Qty":25,
      "EntryPrice":41680.1,
      "Tgt":41595.25,
      "SL":41786.15,
      "LTP":41786.15,
      "TotPL":-2651.25,
      "Investment":153591.0,
      "Period":"Intraday",
      "EntryTime":"2023-04-13 11:03:03",
      "MaxPL":1107.5,
      "aStatus":"SL Reached",
      "MaxPLPerReached":52.21
   }
]
```

I'm returning json output as `JSON.parse(sus);`:

```
{
    "ScripName": "BANKNIFTY23APRFUT",
    "BuySell": "BUY",
    "Qty": 25,
    "EntryPrice": 41872.75,
    "Tgt": 42105.15,
    "SL": 42027.7,
    "LTP": 42105.15,
    "TotPL": 5810,
    "Investment": 154301,
    "Period": "Intraday",
    "EntryTime": "2023-04-13 13:40:57",
    "MaxPL": 5810,
    "aStatus": "TGT Reached",
    "MaxPLPerReached": 100
}
```

I have read [this](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/create-datatable-in-jquery/) concept  for understanding

While I'm adding this data to datatable I'm getting

> cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'style')

How to add dynamic data to datatable?

Comment: I think there is more than one problem here. But as a start: (1) CDN links need cleaning up - for example, where is jQuery? And you have JavaScript libraries marked as being stylesheets.  Go to the official [download](https://datatables.net/download/index) page and get a clean set of libraries. (2) "_I'm getting the Json data and returning that data as `return JSON.parse(sus);`_" - so where is that code? And why not use DataTables' [built-in support for Ajax](https://datatables.net/examples/ajax/index.html) instead? (3) Probably more issues hiding behind these...